# how to shell script regex perfect matching?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a Bash script file that matches a regex.

My regex script file:

```
if [[ "$image" =~ [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}\-[0-9]+$ ]]; then
```

I need to pass cases that only match `0.0.0.0-0000`

These are my inputs and results.

> pass : 0.0.0.0-0000

> pass : 0.0.0.0.0.0-0000  << Unwanted match

> no   : 0.0.0.0-word

> no   : 0.0.0.0

As I marked above `0.0.0.0.0.0-0000` gets a match with my regex.

My question is how can I modify my regex to only match the pattern `0.0.0.0-0000`?

Comment: You can append an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string `if [[ "$image" =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}\-[0-9]+$ ]]; then`

Comment: Thank you for replay @The fourth bird
you r all right! 

i missed anchor ^

XD thank you! have a good days! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved.

The follow answer to up @The fourth bird
i missed anchor(^).
To clarify the starting and ending points, It should be between '^' and '$'.

You can refer to answer

```
if [[ "$image" =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}\-[0-9]+$ ]]; @The fourth bird Jul 11 at 8:43
```

Thank you for replayers XD

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to match up some sort of IP address like String I came up with this regex.

```
^(\d+\.?){4}-\d+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6peafo/1)

Note the `\d+` in first capturing group `(\d+\.?)` which will match any number before a `.`. If the only starting pattern is `0.0.0.0`, you can remove the `+` mark here to only match one digit character.

Explanation:

`^` - Captures start of a String

`(\d+\.?){4}` - Captures a number that ends with a optional `.` character 4 times in a row capturing `0.0.0.0`

`-\d+` - Captures `-` character and sequence of digits in a row capturing `-0000`

Comment: `(\d+\.?){4}` captures `1111` as well

Comment: Thank you for your replay @Pubudu Sitinamaluwa
but i think that match up some IP address, i came up this regex
> (\d+)(\.\d+){3} or (\d+\.){3}(\d+)
as well

Comment: @Philippe That can be fixed by removing the `+` as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @heeyoungeom It can match IP addresses, Yes! But it also can match what you asked. Did this resolved your problem?

Comment: What I meant is that `(\d+\.?){4}` can match invalid IP addresses like `11.11.1111`

Comment: yes i solved it. 

you can see that @The fourth bird answer

Comment: @Philippe oh. i see that thank you for your answer

Comment: @heeyoungeom Did this solved your issue? Please let me know. And don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue. :)

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa ok i can :) you can see this solved issue, and you can see `The fourth bird` answer 
Thank you for replay :)